# calling the constructor for the object that defined inside my function

Tags: c++

I defined a class named "Uno" and after that i definee a function named "foo" that had an object from this class in its body. I am wondering what is the problem that the constructor hadn't called by invoking the funation in my "main()", Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Uno{
public:
    Uno(){cout << "X";}
};

Uno foo(Uno d){
    Uno e = d;
    return e;
}

int main(){
    Uno u;
    foo(u);
}
```

Comment: You do not construct a new clean object, when you call `foo` you construct a copy, implicit default copy constructor is called, that has no body.

Comment: oh yes!!!! you are right

Comment: When in doubt - attach a debugger, put a breakpoint in the function; then look at the callstack so that you can see why every constructor is called